# Retag or synonymize [windows-forms-app] to [winforms]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [windows-forms-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms-app) seems to have appeared very recently (oldest post is 11 days ago) and it currently has 10 questions, all of which are related to WinForms.

**Should this be added as a synonym to [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) or should we retag the existing posts so that the tag gets removed?** As I said, there are only 10 posts at the moment so I could single-handedly retag them (distributing my edits over the course of an hour or so) but I just wanted to make sure if that's the best course of action first.